# How to sent data to a server in a object formart using post

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, post

can someone please help me, I'm trying to post user data to the user in an object format but it's not submitting in the correct format that I want please can someone help I don't want it to make a new object. here is how I want it to submit

`{"birthdate":"1998","email":"jo@joe.com","firstname":"jo","lastname":"david","phone":"012345678","sex":"male","identifier":"32323232","username":"joe","password":"Kdsdsdsddew32","country":"sa","affiliate":"3232"}`

but it is submitting like this
`{"user":{"birthdate":"1998","email":"jo@joe.com","firstname":"jo","lastname":"david","phone":"012345678","sex":"male","identifier":"32323232","username":"joe","password":"Kdsdsdsddew32","country":"sa","affiliate":"3232"}}`

HERE IS MY CODE

```
 constructor(private http: Http, private htp: HttpClient) {

let user = {
  birthdate: '',
  email: 'jo@joe.com',
  firstname: 'jo',
  lastname: 'david',
  phone: '012345678',
  sex: 'male',
  identifier: '43425',
  username: 'joe',
  password: 'Kdsdsdsddew32',
  country: 'sa',
  affiliate: '3232'
};


const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});

const params = new FormData();
// params.append('token', authResult.idToken);
params.append('', JSON.stringify(user));

this.htp.post(' http://192.168.66:323/test',  {user}, {headers}).
subscribe(data => {
  this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

}

Comment: `this.htp.post(' http://192.168.66:323/test',  {...user}, {headers})` will make new object will all user properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular handles JSON conversions automatically. Just pass the object variable to the POST method, and if the server correctly sends back JSON data with the correct headers, Angular will automatically parse the response and return a javascript object (as if you had already done JSON.parse)

```
sendData(data) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };

  return this.http.post("https://example.com/api", data, httpOptions);
}
```

And then somewhere else...

```
const user = {
  name: "John"
}
dataService.sendData(user)
  .subscribe(response => {
    ...
  });
```

**The reason why** you are getting `user: {...}` encapsulation is because of the following line:

`this.htp.post(' http://192.168.66:323/test',  {user}, {headers}).`

You are creating a new object, and assigning the `user` key in this new object as the `user` variable you defined with `let user = {`.

It's a Javascript shorthand, and is the same as doing `this.http.post("...", { user: user }, { headers: headers })`. You don't have to create new objects, just pass the original object.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add

```
this.htp.post(' http://192.168.66:323/test', user, {headers})
```

without the brackets.  It is already an object